# Standardize x same as y

Tags: regression, linear-model, standardization

I am fitting a linear regression (X and Y are all continuous) and I want to standardize X to range [0,1] due to the nature of the project. I am wondering do I need to standardize y the same way? If I standardize X to range [0,1] and normalize Y (mean 0 and variance 1), can I still omit $\beta_0$ in my regression model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just check.

The linear regression estimates are found by minimizing the loss function:

$$L(\beta_0, \beta_1) = \sum_i (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x)^2 $$

At the minimum, the partial derivative with respect to $\beta_0$ must vanish:

$$ 0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta_0} = -2 \sum_i (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x_i) = -2 \sum_i y_i + 2 n \beta_0 - 2 \beta_1 \sum_i x_i $$

If $x$ is centered, then $\sum_i x_i = 0$, so this equality simplifies to

$$ \beta_0 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i y_i $$

So, if $x$ is centered, then the intercept in regression is equal to the mean of $y$.  If $y_i$ is also centered, then the intercept will be zero.

Note that this does not work if you scale $x$ into the interval $[0, 1]$.  In this case $x$ can be centered only if it is identically zero.  You must *center* $x$ to get the effect.